# Add Table in Header with image

Tags: tables, graphics, header-footer

I'm trying to create question paper using Latex. Sample copy of expected header for first page is mentioned below. Note: Image above "First Page Header". Can you please suggest, how can I add table in header with Image on left hand-side as mentioned below. Is there any recommended package? 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save the table in a box and call it with `\usebox` in the header.

In this example, I use the `tabularx` package because you can then force the table to fit the width of the page.  I also used the `multirow` package to allow the image to span multiple rows of the table.  Forcing *height* is a bit more difficult.  So, I just tried a couple of values for resetting `\arraystretch` and the height of the included image to get the appearance to look like a good fit.

Also, I'm not sure how you want the header placed.  I passed the key `includehead` to the `geometry` package to embed the header in the textbody.  It doesn't have to be done this way, but otherwise you'll have to play with the placement.  Or you can make the `top=0.5in` or something like that to get a better appearance for the header and margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%% set up and width for the tabularx environment to expand and fit to.
\newlength{\headerwidth}
\setlength{\headerwidth}{\textwidth}
\newsavebox{\myheader}
\begin{lrbox}{\myheader}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\headerwidth}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.29}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\headerwidth}{|@{}c@{}|c|X|c|}\hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=0.65in]{example-image-a}}
                                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ TEXT ONE VALUE }                 & Text Four \\\cline{2-3}
                                                & \multirow{2}{*}{1234} & \centering\textbf{Text two}   &           \\\cline{3-3}
                                                &                       & \centering\textbf{Text Three} &           \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \par
    \bfseries
    Time: 45 Min \hspace*{\fill} 
    Date:        \hspace*{\fill}
    Marks:45
    \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
%% Setting up the header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{\usebox{\myheader}}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Addendum

I got a bit frustrated with the `multirow` package not really lining things up the way I would like them to.  So here's an example that avoids using the `multirow` package.  Instead, I use `\raisebox` to adjust the placement of the image and the number `1234`.

I wanted to center the image.  Since the baseline of the image in the bottom of the graphic, I used `\raisebox` to raise the image by half its height.  To keep this from affecting the height of the *current* row, I used the optional arguments to `\raisebox` to ensure that it had no height or depth.

Also, to help *preserve* a uniformity in the appearance of the rows, I created some struts.  For lack of a better name, the one I'm calling a *horizontal* "strut" (someone please tell the correct terminology for this use of an invisible box which takes up horizontal space).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,top=0.5in,headheight=5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%% some invisible "struts" to help define the structures and row heights.
\newcommand{\aevstrut}{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}
\newcommand{\aehstrut}{\rule{0.45em}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\textfour}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \aevstrut\aehstrut &
        \aehstrut &
        \aehstrut &
        \aehstrut \\\hline
    \end{tabular}}
%% set up and width for the tabularx environment to expand and fit to.
\newlength{\headerwidth}
\setlength{\headerwidth}{\textwidth}
\newsavebox{\myheader}
\begin{lrbox}{\myheader}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\headerwidth}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.29}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\headerwidth}{|@{}c@{}|c|X|c|}\hline
                                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ TEXT ONE VALUE }                             & {\aevstrut}Text Four \\\cline{2-3}
        \raisebox{\dimexpr0.73ex-0.5\totalheight\relax}[0pt][0pt]
                 {\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.65in+1.5ex\relax]{example-image-a}}%
                                                &                                   & \centering\textbf{TEXT TWO}   & {\aevstrut}\textfour \\\cline{3-3}
                                                & \raisebox{2.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{1234}  & \centering\textbf{TEXT THREE} & {\aevstrut}          \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace{-0.5ex}\par
    \bfseries
    Time: 45 Min \hspace*{\fill} 
    Date:        \hspace*{\fill}
    Marks:45
    \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
%% Setting up the header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{\usebox{\myheader}}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to restrict chead only on the first page? Currently it's appearing on all pages.

Comment: As a workaround , i added it in \fbox{\usebox{\myheader}} FYI: I'm using documentclass{exam}

Comment: Just place `\chead{<new content>}` with text that will definitely appear starting on the second page.  `<new content>` can be anything including an empty string.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also do something like `\chead{\ifnum\thepage=1\usebox{\myheader}\else$<$other content$>$\fi}` in the preamble.