# How can I create a header with boxes?

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I'm having trouble creating a header with boxes, images and other features.
Is it possible to create a header like the following one in LaTeX? How?

[image: Header]

Comment: Have you consider [this solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119584/22413)?

Comment: Thanks, that solution worked. But the only problem unsolved is for the page number. Im using Paga `\thepage` but the number does not change in each page. It still shows 1 in all the pages

Comment: If you're calling `\thepage` from within the `lrbox` then that's exactly the result you would get.  Instead, if you're following the suggested link, write `\rhead{\thepage}` or possibly something like `\rhead{\raisebox{<dim>}[0pt][0pt]{\thepage}}` where `<dim>` is some positive/negative dimension that will help line the page number where you would like it.